# sed command to replace a value in config file

Tags: sed, text-processing

I  am using this command:

```
sed -i  's/\(^TestT_STOA_TS1901=\).*/\1N/'/app/test/must/untuio.cf
```

And I am getting this error:

```
XXXXXXXXX:/app/test/must>sed -i  's/\(^TestT_STOA_TS1901=\).*/\1N/'/app/test/must/untuio.cf
sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'
```

Why is this happening? How can I replace a value in a config file?

Answer (score 8):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\(^Key2=\).*/\1Value4/' file
```

The `-i` flag activates `sed`s in-place editing. It searches for a line that begins with `Key2=` and replaces the line with the key (`\1`) followed by the new value `Value4`.

**Edit**:

If you have slashes or other command characters used in `sed`, you have to escape them:

```
sed -i 's/\(^Key2=\).*/\1long\/value\'/with\$many\"strange\^characters/' /path/to/file
```

**Edit 2**: In your case:

```
sed -i  's/\(^TestT_STOA_TS1901=\).*/\1N/' /app/test/must/untuio.cf
```

Comment: sed -i 's/\(^Key2=\).*/\1Value4/' file...this didnt work

Comment: @canonical Use the exact command as in my answer. I used backslashes before the brackets.

Comment: i get this error : sed: -e expression #1, char 33: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @canonical Has the string you want to replace slashes / in it? (`Value4` in the example). If yes, you need to escape them: `sed -i 's/\(^Key2=\).*/\1value\/to\/replace/' file`. Or post the **exact** command you entered.

Comment: this is the exact command i used                              sed -i  's/\(^TestT_STOA_TS1901=\).*/\1N/'/app/test/must/untuio.cf                           I am somehow missing the blackslash when pasting here.But i am actually using it

Comment: @canonical See the edit of my answer. Else we need the **exact** command and error. Post it in your question or between backticks or see http://askubuntu.com/editing-help

Comment: I edited the  question now

Comment: @canonical Use this: `sed -i  's/\(^TestT_STOA_TS1901=\).*/\1N/' /app/test/must/untuio.cf`. After between the sed command and the file must be a **space**, else it is interpreted as command, and therefore spits an error.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of ways :

1. Probably the most straight forward way, matching the appropriate key by `/Key2/` and then replacing `Value2` with `Value4` :

   ```
   $ sed '/Key2/ s/Value2/Value4/' foo.txt 
   Key1=Value1            
   Key2=Value4          
   Key3=Value3
   ```
2. If you know that the digits will come at last and if you just want to replace those digit(s) with something else (here replacing `2` with `4`) :

   ```
   $ sed '/Key2/ s/[[:digit:]]\+$/4/' foo.txt 
   Key1=Value1
   Key2=Value4
   Key3=Value3
   ```

I also have some other ways on top of my head but they depends on your use case. Let us know if these would suffice.

Your mistakes in `sed -i -e '/KEY=/ s/= .*/= new_value/' /path/to/file` :

- As per your example, no `Key` will be matched with `/KEY=/` as it is not in proper cases and there is a number after `Key` and `=` is after that
- `s/= .*/= new_value/`, from your example there is no space after `=` but your pattern-substitution seems it has a space in the actual file. Otherwise as far as your given example is concerned there is no space after `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`? **=)**

```
awk -F= '$1=="Key2" {printf "%s=%s\n",$1,"Value4"; next}1' your_input_file
```

---

*Example*

The input file `foo`

`cat foo`

```
Key1=Value1            
Key2=Value2          
Key3=Value3
```

The command output

```
% awk -F= ' $1=="Key2" {printf "%s=%s\n",$1,"Value4"; next}1' foo
Key1=Value1            
Key2=Value4
Key3=Value3
```

Comment: Note you can also say `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} $1=="Key2" {$2="Value4"}1' file` so you don't have to "next".

Comment: @canonical  If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** on the left hand site of my answer now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask